# Take a string but need react component

Tags: reactjs

I have some object like:

```
'key': { a: 'aa', b:'bb', c: <Component/> }
```

It object returned as property in some object:

```
{item.a}
{item.b}
{item.c}
```

item.c - is a string, but im need take real component in render. Very thanks for any answer!!!

Comment: Show us more code. What you describe is working https://codesandbox.io/s/ry1zzy2n8q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would convert your values to arrow functions.

Working example :

```js
const data = { 
    a: () => 'aa',
    b: () => 'bb',
    c: () => <Component />
}

const App = props =>
    <div>
        {data.a()}
        {data.b()}
        {data.c()}
    </div>

const Component = props => <p>Comp</p>

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Simply storing your component in a variable will also* work :

```js
const Component = props => <p>Comp</p>

const data = { 
    a: 'aa',
    b: 'bb',
    c: <Component />
}

const App = props =>
    <div>
        {data.a}
        {data.b}
        {data.c}
    </div>


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Comment: Its real work, thanks. I convert to func, and in parent render call it. Thats all. Great!

Comment: It seems that the only problem is the order in which your components are imported/declared. I was wrong, your code should work as it is

Answer (score -1):

It should work without any magic, Component here is a function and calling item.c should give you the reference to the function. Double check your code, if it doesn't work then you need to provide more details like how you are calling it.